# How do I keep text with the equation in centering math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I really like the format of centering math mode `\[\]` (especially when it comes to the display of limits) however I wish to keep the text with the equation sometimes.
If you have another way of doing it that looks cleaner or works better, I'd appreciate that as well. Thanks

---

Examples;

[image: Ex-1]

[image: Ex-2] - Centering Math Mode limit

[image: Ex-3] - Inline Math Mode limit

Comment: @youthdoo Unfortunately not. The x\to1 shows up to the right of the \lim, whereas I'm looking for it to be under it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the subscript. Use ```$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}$```.

Comment: @youthdoo that works beautifully, thank you.